# Companion objects benefits of posibility to implement interfaces

Tags: scala, kotlin, companion-object, kotlin-companion

Why in Kotlin/Scala companion objects can implements some interfaces, what benefits this can have? When is useful to use this feature?

Comment: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/what-is-the-advantage-of-companion-object-vs-static-keyword/4034

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `companion object`s are `object`s, `object`s can implement interfaces (or extend classes), and there is no good reason to disallow it for `companion object`s in particular.

One common use in Scala is for factories: e.g. `Seq`, `List`, `Vector` etc. companion objects all extend [`TraversableFactory`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/collection/generic/TraversableFactory.html) so you can write code working with a `TraversableFactory` and pass any of them to construct the type you want. E.g.

```
def build[CC[X] <: Traversable[X] with GenericTraversableTemplate[X, CC], A](factory: TraversableFactory[CC])(elems: A*) = factory(elems)

// build(List)(1,2,3) == List(1, 2, 3)
// build(Set)(1,2,3) == Set(1, 2, 3)
```

Similarly, all case class companion objects extend function types.

Comment: can you please add an example of "you can write code working with a TraversableFactory and pass any of them to construct the type you want" ? thanks

Comment: Here is a rather trivial example.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `companion object`s and inheritance for some level of class-lavel or static polymorphism.

### Example 1: Factories

Consider an interface

```
interface Factory<T> {
    fun create(): T
}
```

Now, we create a class whose companion object implements it

```
class Foo {
    companion object: Factory<Foo> {
        override fun create() = Foo()
    }
}
```

Now we can create an extension function for all factories to create and e.g. log the object.

```
fun <T> Factory<T>.createAndLog(): T {
    val t = create()
    println(t)
    return t
}
```

Und use it like so

```
Foo.createAndLog()
```

### Example 2: Queries

Consider a marker interface

```
interface Queryable<T>
```

We now have two classes `User` and `Article` that represent tables in a database whose `companion object` implements the interface.

```
class User(val id: String) {
    companion object: Queryable<User> {}
}

class Article(val authorId: String) {
    companion object: : Queryable<Article> {}
}
```

We can now define an extension function to create a query from the class

```
fun <T> Queryable<T>.query() = db.createQuery<T>()
```

which we can call as

```
User.query()
//or
Article.query()
```

Comment: But why not to implement interfaces by classes themselves?

Comment: I'm calling the functions on the _class_, not an _instance_ of the class. As you can see from the last example, I never call the constructor of `User`or `Article`.

Comment: Yes, I see, but what benefits this have, to call functions on the _class_ and not on _instance_?

Comment: That's a very fundamental question. You could as well ask "Why do we need `companion object`s?" or "Why do we need `static` in Java?". I would recommend finding a satisfying answer to those questions before coming back to your original question.

Comment: I understand why we need companion object and static, mostly for namespacing, but why companion object need to implement some interface when class itself can implement interfaces, I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

You use singleton object when you need only one instance of particular class in program.

E.g. Scala's [`Nil`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.4/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L425) implements `List[Nothing]`. Rather than every type of list to implement *it's particular* `Nil` there is just one of them.

In [typeclass pattern](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html), where you have just one `implicit object` for corresponding implementation.

Also, where you'd create a `public static Something` in Java, you'd create that in a companion object.

I personally found them useful for implementing an sbt plugin, that renders `object Blah extends Renderable` to files `blah.html`. Find more about usefulness [here](https://github.com/sake92/sbt-hepek). I **had to know that it implements** that trait!